# How to print json data in a post request in python3?

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

Here is my code :

```
from requests import post

peer2profit = post("https://peer2profit.com/api/getpeers",data={"_token":"mytoken"}) 
print(peer2profit.json())
```

Here is what i expect the output to be :

```
{
    "totalPeer": 10,
    "balance": 0.48045,
    "peers": [
        {
            "id": 108270438,
            "serial": null,
            "online": 1,
            "territorial_dispute": "",
            "version": "3.4bA",
            "platform": "ANDROID",
            "ip": "my ip",
            "country": "HR",

  And much more...
```

Here is what i get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\skepp\Desktop\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    peer2profit = post("https://peer2profit.com/api/getpeers",headers={'accept': 'application/json'},data={"_token": "my token"}).json()['peers']
  File "C:\Users\skepp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\skepp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\skepp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\skepp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I had this error before but i dont know how to fix it!

I tried this post request in 2 diffrent tool for http requests and it worked!

Here are some images :
[RestMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SzIF.png)
[Requestttp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqibR.png)

Comment: Maybe your request is incorrect. What is the status (`peer2profit.status`) returned by the API that you accessed?

Comment: the response is 200 as always

Comment: I had the same error because site returned none. I was doing request to a wrong url so I fixed it

Answer (score -1):

I don't see that you have imported JSON and parsed it.

```
from requests import post
import json

peer2profit = post("https://peer2profit.com/api/getpeers",data={"_token":"mytoken"}) 

# Parse it
parsed = json.loads(peer2profit)

# Output the entire dictionary 
print(parsed.json())
```

Comment: json() call used in question is from requests library

Comment: Now i get this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/EarningMonitor/test2.py", line 37, in <module>
    parsed = json.loads(peer2profit)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response

Comment: some request you are sending has datatype string or bool but you are sending it as int